# Lua equivalent to shlex?

Tags: python, parsing, lua, command-line-arguments

Is there a Lua equivalent for python's [shlex](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-shlex.html) library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a reference to a project called [LuaParse](http://luaparse.luaforge.net/):

> LuaParse includes Blex, a general purpose pure-Lua lexer, and lparse, a pure-Lua Lua parser, as well as a variety of utility functions and a prototype package management system.

Maybe this will meed your needs.

Answer (score 4):

See also [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html).

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to parse a shell-like language (which appears to be shlex's actual design goal) then writing a grammar in [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html) as [lhf suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851940/lua-equivalent-to-shlex/1853465#1853465) is probably the right answer. However, it is not all that easy to write a grammar that completely implements the hodgepodge of layered quoting rules that shells actually follow. As long as you aren't expecting to correctly parse all valid `/bin/sh` (or worse, `csh`) scripts, it should be straightforward to write a grammar that is useful.

If the goal is actually to create a sensible "little language" for configuration files or application scripting, then I'd suggest that Lua itself is already very close to being that language. It was originally designed with data description in mind, and its parser is quite adept at handling even fairly large data declarations. See [section 10.1 of PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/10.1.html) for one example of how to use Lua this way. The later [chapter 25](http://www.lua.org/pil/25.html) describes integration of Lua with a larger application for the specific use case of configuration, and demonstrates a number of approaches.

Comment: I originally asked this because i thought shlex was a commandline parsing tool :)

Answer (score 1):

See also `gg`, `mlp` and `clopts` modules from [Metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/manual000.html).

Those are 'not-quite' Lua (as Metalua is a separate language), but may provide some useful insights. Also Metalua code compiles into plain Lua bytecode, so it is reusable.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dromozoa/dromozoa-shlex has shlex.split implementation.

Disclaimer: It's GPL-3 licensed.